# Sending int via socket from Java to C - strange results

Tags: java, c, sockets, network-programming

I have a simple server written in Java, that just sends an Integer to a connected client. I have a client written in C, that connects to the server and prints out the received Integer.

My problem is that the result varies. About half of the times executing the client I get the correct result (234), but other times I get 8323072.

This is the server:

```
class TCPServer {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
     ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);

     while(true)
     {
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("welcomeSocket.accept() called");
        DataInputStream inFromClient = new DataInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

        outToClient.writeInt(234);
     }
  }
```

}

And this is the client:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 4){
        printUsage();
        return;
    }

    char* serverIP = argv[1];
    char* serverPortC = argv[2];
    char* integerToSendC = argv[3];

    int serverPort = atoi(serverPortC);
    int integerToSend = atoi(integerToSendC);

    int socketDesc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(socketDesc < 0) {
        printf("Error when creating socket\n");
        return;
    } 

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(serverPort);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, serverIP, &serverAddr.sin_addr);

    int connection = connect(socketDesc, (struct sockaddr*) &serverAddr, sizeof serverAddr);

    if(connection < 0) {
        printf("Error when establishing connection\n");
        return;
    }

    char intBuffer[4];

    if(recv(socketDesc, intBuffer, sizeof intBuffer, 0) == -1){
        printf("Error while receiving Integer\n");
    }

    int receivedInt = ntohl(*((int *) &intBuffer));

    printf("Received int: %d\n", receivedInt);

    close(socketDesc);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: 
So in the end I did something like this, just for anybody who has the same problem:

```
while(receivedBytes < 4){
    int readBytes = read(receiverSocket, &intBuffer, (sizeof intBuffer) - receivedBytes, receivedBytes);
    receivedInteger += (intBuffer << (8*receivedBytes));
    receivedBytes += readBytes;
}
```

Comment: Could possible be because of how many bytes are assigned for `int` in Java and C and their associated sub-boundaries. Try sending small numbers. If Java assigns 4 bytes for int, C assigns 2 bytes. So the range is way less in C

Comment: that number is 2**16 * 127 (i.e. the third byte all 1's, the bottom two all 0's)

Comment: @LittleChild I would have thought so too, but [DataOutputStream.writeInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt(int)) seems pretty clear on sending four bytes, at least in the 32bit runtime.

Comment: Your cast looks dreadful, not to mention a prime place for a bus error on non-intel hardware. Have you considered just reading into a `int32_t` instead. ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the suggestion, I changed it and thereby avoided the cast, but I still get the same results

Comment: Can you dump the content of your int32_t value both before and after your ntohl() invoke? in hex preferably. Something still doesn't seem to be lining up. Also, you may want to make sure `recv()` actually returned the **4** bytes you were expecting, not just "didn't fail".

Comment: The value returned after `ntohl()` is `0x7F0000`. I.e. 127 is ending up in the third octet. I'm curious to know what it looked like before the `ntohl()` It almost seems you're sometimes only getting partial reads, but even then I would have expected to see at least a 0xEA somewhere in there Odd.

Comment: Dereferencing `char *` as `int` is a bad idea. In this example the stack alignment might be ok, but it is not always the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you be sure you have received `sizeof intBuffer` bytes on the client side? No you can not, as `recv()` might return less bytes then requested.

Mod you code to loop around `recv()` as long as less bytes then requested have been received and no error occurred.

Note that `recv()`ing `0` bytes indicates the connection had been closed by the other side.

Also make sure the server side sends in network byte order.

Also^2: It is good idea to initialise variables (`intBuffer` here), at least during the development phase, will say: prior to the tuning phase.

Comment: It doesn't expain the received value: `123` maps to `00 00 00 7B` on network. The received value `8323072` is `7F 00 00 00`. Even if 1 byte is read, it should not be `7F`.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk: Most propably the other side hung up the connection, `recv()` returned with `0`, so no error message is logged and the `8323072` being printed out for `receivedInt` is simply garbage as `intBuffer` was not initialised prior to  having been passed to `recv()`.

Comment: could be, but this doesn't exactly match the counter-part sources: the DataOutputStream shell send 4 bytes before close.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, looping around read() and taking care of the received bytes finally made it work!

Answer (score -1):

Your problem could be because of the sub-boundaries of the various data types.

In Java, 4 bytes are assigned to `int` and 2 bytes for a `short`.
In C, 4 bytes are for `long` and 2 bytes for `int`.

This means `Java int` -> `C long` and `Java short` -> `C int`.
Now it depends on where your priorities lie.

If you want to perform an intense mathematical calculation in Java and send the result over socket to C, I recommend you do `Java int -> C long` or
If you want to just send small numbers and have the intense calculation done in C, do the `Java short` -> `C int` conversion.

Hope that helped.

Comment: In C, in my computer, 4 bytes for `int`.

Comment: See [DataOutputStream.writeInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt(int)). It appears `writeInt` always writes 4 bytes in big-endian. So long as it is reassembled correctly on the C side as a 4-byte `int` I would expect this to be correct.

Comment: @WhozCraig I do not program in C. I was just referring to the size of basic data types on Wikipedia and it says that C assigns *16 bits* (2 bytes) Hence my answer. If there are mistakes in the answer or if it is wrong in the first place, let me know. I will delete it right away so as not to confuse the OP

Comment: @LittleChild The size of an int in C depends on your compiler settings and target architecture. It can definitely be 32 bit, and the OP seems to indicate that, in his case, it is

Comment: The *minimum* size per the standard (C99 §5.2.4.2.1) of a compliant `int` is 16 bits (15+1sign). But the standard only mandates the value representations as minimum compliance requirements. Nearly every non-embedded C compiler today uses at least 32bit `int`, some 64bit. Wiki likely only lists the standard minimum requirement.

Comment: for future readers... The philosophy of 'C' wrt int was to allow compilers to choose the most efficient representation of a suitable data range while specifying the number of bits in long and short ints. This of course lead to many bugs when an int was passed as a parameter to a method expecting a long or a short - the program might work on some machines and not others depending upon the compilers involved. Thus Java went the other way and specified the number of bits/bytes for each int data type.